# XFN rel=me links to Stack Exchange profiles

Tags: feature-request

The link back to my main website has rel="me", but the link to my other Stack Exchange profiles don't have the "me" tag, so they don't show up as profiles in my [social graph](http://socialgraph-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/findyours.html).

If the links in the accounts tab had the rel="me" tag then I could just include a single link to Stack Overflow on one of my profiles, rather than having to maintain a link back to each individual Stack Exchange profile.

This would be an easy change that, among other things, will make Tim Berners-Lee smile!